# Firestore Compounded query with "or"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add a listener to a firestore collection. Such that it listens to documents specified in the `condition` variable and either has `isPublished` true or the `uid` is equal to the one supplied.

I referred to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#web-modular-api_14).

```
let listenToUserResponses = async ({ uid, condition, callback }) => {
 const q = query(collection(fs, "userResponses"), and(
  where(condition.lhs, condition.operator || "==", condition.rhs),
  or(
   where("isPublished", "==", true),
   where("uid", "==", uid)
  )
 ));
 return onSnapshot(q, (d) => {
  const allDocs = [];
  d.forEach((doc) => {
   allDocs.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
  });
  callback(allDocs)
 });
}
```

However, it is throwing the error

> TypeError: (0 , firebase_firestore__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.or) is not a function

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to [reproduce the problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/firestore-v9-or-query?file=index.js), but your query works fine when I try it.

Are you sure you're on a recent version of the Firestore SDK? In my linked example I use version 9.23.

If that's not the problem, can you try to reproduce the problem in a similar setup so that I can take a look?